# How can we tell that this sum is less than or equal to y?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If we have a series like this:

> $$y + \frac{1}{3!}y^3a^2 + \frac{1}{5!}y^5a^4+  \frac{1}{7!}y^7a^6+ ...$$

How can we intuitively tell that this is the same ~y for specific ranges of a?
It seems to me that it is not the case for a > 1
But I am not sure how obvious it is for a < 1
What is the reasoning for this kind of series?

**UPDATE:**
My question is if the "tail" is some how obviously a non-zero but so small a number that adding that to `y` does not make it so much `> y` so we can ignore the tail

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "$\sim y$"? Note also that your series is just $\frac1a\sinh ay$.

Comment: @MPW: I mean that the tail of the series summed up is so small that it can be neglected and consider that it equals `y`.

Comment: The title seems in contradiction to the question.

Comment: To go from one term to the next the numerator multiplicands are y^2 and a^2 (both constants holding y constant). However the denominator multiplicands are n and n+1 which are unbounded and thus dominate the absolute value taking it to 0.

Comment: @Jim: Well, that's rubbish because unless $a$ or $y$ is zero, the tail is definitely positive. Your meaning is still unclear.

Comment: @MPW:It is positive but the tail is such a small number that we can neglect it completely. That was my question i.e. if that the tail can be ignored due to this reason is somehow obvious

Comment: @Jim: There's no such thing as "the tail". For **ANY** convergent series with positive terms, tails can be selected which are arbitrarily small. They are never zero. The very *definition* of convergence is that this be the case. If you are asking how many terms you need to include so that that neglected tail is of at most some particular size, that's a different question (at least one that makes sense). Whenever you add up a finite number of terms, what's left over is a tail.

Comment: @MPW:For this particular series I think that all the terms after `y` if summed up give a result that is so small that adding it to `y` does not make such a difference. And we can round down to `y`. But I think this is valid only for small values of a

Comment: @Jim: The value of all terms after $y$ summed up is exactly $\frac1a\sinh ay - y$.

Comment: @MPW: But the value `1/a sinhay` has a specific/finite value. Which means that the tail converges to a value that is at most y right?

Answer (score 1):

As MPW notes, this is simply a well known series, so we have

$$y+\frac1{3!}y^3a^2+\frac1{5!}y^5a^4+\dots=\frac1a\sinh(ay)$$

Setting this equal to $y$, we get

$$y=\frac1a\sinh(ay)\implies ay=\sinh(ay)$$

$$z=\sinh(z)\tag{$z=ay$}$$

This has the simple solution $z=0\implies y=0,a=0$.  So, for all $a\ne0$, we have

$$\frac1a\sinh(ay)\sim y\text{ as }y\to0$$

If $a=0$, then we have

$$y+\frac1{3!}y^3a^2+\frac1{5!}y^5a^4+\dots=y$$

---

It is also quite obvious that if $y>0$ and $a\ne0$, then we have

$$y+\frac1{3!}y^3a^2+\frac1{5!}y^5a^4+\dots>y$$

Or if $y<0$ and $a\ne0$, then we have

$$y+\frac1{3!}y^3a^2+\frac1{5!}y^5a^4+\dots<y$$

Comment: For the second part of your answer if `y` > 0 and `a` non zero but very small can the tail be so small that we can ignore it?

Comment: @Jim Depends [how small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) you you think is ignorable.

Comment: If the tail adds up to `0.001` then `y + 0.001` can be round down to `y` right? Like we can "safely" round down `3.001` to `3`